# Downloading files in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, download, content-type

I have a link that allows the user to download a file. Basically I call the controller action that uses `base.File` function. I have few different types of files - pdf, doc, text....Is there a contentType I can specify that would work for all these? Or do I need to specify the correct (matching) contentType for each and every file type?

Answer (score 3):

Use "application/octet-stream" for general purposes.